# Dart DateTime.parse() string date return by ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, dart

I have date string return by ServiceStack : 2013-08-25T12:06:32.8770000 but error when convert to date of Dart

```dart
DateTime.parse(mapAccount[Account.RECCREATED]);
```

it ok when call

```dart
DateTime.parse((mapAccount[Account.RECCREATED] as String).substring(0, 26));
```

Is there anyway to fix it. Thanks you.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Here is error : Breaking on exception: Illegal argument(s): 2013-08-25T12:06:32.8770000

Exception: Illegal argument(s): 2013-08-25T12:06:32.8770000
  DateTime.parse (dart:core/date_time.dart:67:7)

Comment: Same problem for me with web api rest (c#)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the string don't match the internally used regular expression:

```
 r'^([+-]?\d?\d\d\d\d)-?(\d\d)-?(\d\d)(?:[ T](\d\d)(?::?(\d\d)(?::?(\d\d)(.\d{1,6})?)?)? ?([zZ])?)?$'
```

But the regular expression doesn't support more that 6 digits for the milliseconds (and microseconds) part, but you supply 7 digits.
The documentation does not state which formats are supported, but gives some examples. They only state that they support a *subset* of ISO 8601.

Looks like your solution is the only one a the moment.
Not sure if this should be treaded as a bug, but if you think it is a bug, create a bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/entry).

See the docs about [`DateTime.parse`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/DateTime.html#parse) for more details. Looks like the problems with the [`parse`](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=1878) function is already in the bug tracker.